# AS3 - Loader class: Resize external swf to it's original stage size

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, loader, stage

Here is my problem (unfortunatelly didn't find solution @google):

I'm loading external swf[AS2] into main swf[AS3] using Loader class. 
The main swf is 800 x 600 and the external swf is 300 x 200.

After adding the external swf to the main swf the external swf expands it's size from 300 x 200 to the main swf's size: 800 x 600.

How can i prevent this? I want the loaded swf to save it's original size.

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no code in the AS2 swf that itself is doing the expanding, I think what you need to do in AS3 is:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Comment: The cause of the problem is that the loaded swf has hardcoded onResize handler, so without the source nothing can be done to keep it's original stage size after loading to another swf.

Thx